# Fixing the cryptic SSRS error - rsServerConfigurationError

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

My SSRS 2008 service is started in windows services. It is running and uses the Local System as a logon, the same one I used during installation of BIDS. I started SSRS 2008R2 entered the url - `http://MYCOMPUTER:80/ReportServer_SS2008` into internet explorer. I saw a pop up for user and password. After entering the windows login I use for my computer, I get an error - rsServerConfigurationError. There is no other information provided. I don't have any clue as to why this is happening. How do I fix this ?

**EDIT -**

Error parts only of my report server log file -

**Main complaint - No URLs specifed for Application ReportManager.**

```
configmanager!DefaultDomain!15c8!SomeDate e ERROR: 
No URLs specifed for Application ReportServerWebService. 
It will be ignored.configmanager!DefaultDomain!15c8!SomeDate 
e ERROR: Failed to get report server url reservations.
configmanager!DefaultDomain!15c8!SomeDate e ERROR: Failed 
to get report server url reservations.
configmanager!DefaultDomain!15c8!SomeDate w WARN: 
IsApplicationUrlSubsetOfReportServer() -- Failed to get 
report server url reservations. configmanager!
WindowsService_1!1a1c!SomeDate e ERROR: Failed to get 
report server url reservations. configmanager!
WindowsService_1!1a1c!SomeDate e ERROR: Failed to get 
report server url reservations. configmanager!
WindowsService_1!1a1c!SomeDate w WARN: 
IsApplicationUrlSubsetOfReportServer() -- 
Failed to get report server url reservations.
configmanager!WindowsService_1!1a1c!SomeDate i 
INFO: Using report server internal url .
configmanager!WindowsService_1!1a1c!SomeDate i 
INFO: Using report server external url .
configmanager!WindowsService_1!1a1c!SomeDate i 
INFO: Using url root .
configmanager!DefaultDomain!1a1c!SomeDate e 
ERROR: Failed to get report server url reservations.
configmanager!DefaultDomain!1a1c!SomeDate e 
ERROR: Failed to get report server url reservations.
configmanager!DefaultDomain!1a1c!SomeDate w WARN: 
IsApplicationUrlSubsetOfReportServer() 
-- Failed to get report server url reservations.
configmanager!DefaultDomain!1a1c!SomeDate i 
INFO: Using report server internal url .
configmanager!DefaultDomain!1a1c!SomeDate i 
INFO: Using report server external url .
configmanager!DefaultDomain!15c8!OneMoreDate e 
ERROR: No URLs specifed for Application ReportManager. It will be ignored.
```

Comment: This means that there is an error in the configuration information. Can you open the Configuration Manager (Microsoft Sql Server 2008 > Configuration Tools > Reporting Services Configuration Manager) and [check the settings](http://fczaja.blogspot.com.au/2010/10/report-server-has-encountered.html)?

Comment: Additionally, check the LogFiles in the Report Server directory - the error preventing it from starting will be near the bottom of the most recent log file.

Comment: @ChrisLätta - Thanks. I tried the steps in the link and I get a login screen which asks me to enter a password for myComputer/myUserName account. I enter my windows user password and I get the screen again into which I enter the info again. This happens 3 times and finally, I get a blank page.

Comment: @kyzen - I found my latest SSRS log in the SSRS directory. It is 100 lines. How do I find out the source of the error from this log ?

Comment: Folder for SSRS log files - C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.SS2008\Reporting Services\LogFiles

Comment: Step 1:  Do a ctrl+f for "error".  If you can't find anything useful, scrub out any sensitive information, and post the logs somewhere that we can see them.

Comment: I clicked the report server URL again and finally got a new error - The permissions granted to user 'userpc\user' are insufficient for performing this operation. (rsAccessDenied) . Lets see if I can get past this.

Comment: @kyzen - thanks. I tried several things after you showed me the logs. I finally got the damned thing to work.